# How to collect the contents of a tcolorbox instead of the titles?

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, tcolorbox

I have a question/answer `tcolorbox` and I want to make it so that when I collect them in a list of questions it prints the contents of the upper box instead of the title of the box.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside={questions}] {question}{+O{}}{ %
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!15!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white];
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Question:},
label={questions@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad
}


\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{Mycolor1}{red!40!black}
\newcommand{\solution}{\tcblower \textbf{\textcolor{Mycolor1}  {Solution:}}\hphantom{so}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\section{Some problems}
\tcblistof[\section*]{questions}{List of Questions}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{question}
the question
\solution
the solution
\end{question}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{question}
another question
\solution
its solution
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas? I tried using

```
\NewEnviron{objectives}
 {%
  \addcontentsline{obj}{obj}{%
    \noexpand\unexpanded{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
  }%
 }
```

But I have no idea how to adapt that for a colorbox

Comment: I don't know what the use of this is really?The content might be a very long text, with equations or tables etc. Shall this really appear in list of 'something'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christian I don't understand what do you want to do, but with the help of `list entry` and an auxiliary command you can type a list of questions contents. It seems to even work with long lines or broken lines.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside={questions}]{question}{O{}}{ %
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!15!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white];
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Question:},
label={questions@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
#1
}


\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{Mycolor1}{red!40!black}

\newcommand{\solution}{\tcblower \textbf{\textcolor{Mycolor1}  {Solution:}}\hphantom{so}}

\newcommand{\listquestion}[2]{%
    \begin{question}[list entry={#1}]
    #1
    \solution
    #2
    \end{question}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}

\section{Some problems}

\tcblistof[\section*]{questions}{List of Questions}

Bla bla bla

\listquestion{this question is a very long question which needs more than one line to be typed}{the solution}

Bla bla bla

\listquestion{another question\\ with a second line}{its solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]